# Java android ContextCompat don't have a method checkSelfPermission

Tags: java, android

Hi I have an old project in eclipse and I when I try checkSelfPermission like this :

```
 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

I don't have a method `checkSelfPermission` on `ContextCompat`

Comment: use ActivityCompact instead

Comment: @DivyeshPatel eclipse doesn't see a ActivityCompact

Comment: have you import support v4 library in eclipse?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel yes I do

Comment: @DivyeshPatel look I have imports : http://static.pokazywarka.pl/5/9/l/4de15dc23c585811174d80d09e85c44c_orig.jpg

Comment: You need to use at least version 23 of the support library.

Comment: @MikeM. Where can I get a good library?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with:

`ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);`

and replace the import line

`import android.support.v4.app.ContextCompat`

with

`import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat`

Comment: I did what  you said but all the time I have this problem : The method checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity, String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat

Comment: try replacing `this` with `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: All time nothink

Comment: have you overridden the base checkSelfPermission() method?

Comment: No I don't Override this method

Comment: I can only Override  checkPermission

Comment: Try editing your build.gradle file to include the android v4 support library.

Comment: I don't use in eclipse gradle , this is old project not my , and I don't know how I can in eclipse use a gradle

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that. I was under the assumption that you were using Android Studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139325/discussion-between-pawel-o-and-nocturnal-beast).